# Watching Ethereum Contract State

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I want to be able to watch the state/storage of an ethereum contract and know for instance when some conditions are satisfied. For instance, one account value is greater than 200, another map has more than 30 keys, etc.

What can I use for this? Is there a SaaS platform that can be used for this purpose?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I am NOT the owner of the contract. I simply want to watch somebody's else contract.

Answer (score 0):

Events are supported for this purpose.

[Event Documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#events)

Example:

```
contract SomeContract {
  struct AccountData {
    address account;
    uint value;
  }

  ...
  event AccountValueChange(address account, uint value, bytes msg);
  ...

  function someAction() {
    AccountData accountData;

    // some activity with accountData...

    if (accountData.value > 200) {
      AccountValueChange(accountData.address, accountData.value, "Some message");
    }
  }
}
```

You can listen for the events in your client

```
const someContract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address);

myContract.events.AccountValueChange({
    filter: {//Optional event filters},
    fromBlock: 0
}, function(error, event){ console.log(event); })
.on('data', function(event){
    console.log(event);
})
.on('error', console.error);
```

EDIT: Updated client code to listen to all events instead of just a single fired event.

Comment: Thanks. I added some edit to the original post. I forgot to mention that I am not the owner of the contract. I want to watch something that has been deployed by a third party.

Comment: You don't need to be the owner of the contract to listen to its events. All you need is the ABI, the contract address, and the name of the event.

For filtering, you can still specify a filter parameter as long as the data you want to filter by has been marked as indexed by the owner of the contract. If not, you would have to listen to all events and filter yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that you'll have to probe the EVM yourself to make this happen and then run your own node on the network that you can monitor. There is no public project I can find that will do this, and the RPC api does not provide any way to accomplish it. I used a modified Geth binary with custom transaction filters coded in and mailgun to send me emails when my conditions were met.

Events will not solve your issue because events must be included in the contract at the time of creation.